# Logging application (a struts + ejb3 web application) specific logs to my own log file while server (Glassfish) specific logs to server.log

Tags: logging, glassfish, log4j

I am working on an enterprise application that is developed on Struts1.3 + EJB3.0 + Glassfish2.1.1.

The requirement is to route my application logs to a file that I have defined and all server specific logs should go to glassfish's default logger i.e. `server.log`.

I'm using `log4j-1.2.15.jar` and `log4j.properties`. The content of this property file is as --

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
og4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, ROOT, CONSOLE
log4j.appender.ROOT=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ROOT.File=/appl/svc_elcpn/domains/elcpn_domain1/logs/SmartLog.log
log4j.appender.ROOT.MaxFileSize=4000KB
log4j.appender.ROOT.MaxBackupIndex=10

log4j.appender.ROOT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ROOT.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss}] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss}] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Application logs are nicely going to `SmartLog.log` (my log file) but it is also going to `server.log`.

The question is how to block it going to `server.log` (the default log file)?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should remove `CONSOLE` logger from your `log4j.properties`.